# How to authenticate a user with an external webservice

Tags: login, rest-api, core-modifications

I was asked to login wordpress with an external webservice and at the same time to use the original wordpress database, ie, the webservice would only obtain data for the user profile and its authentication and it would not be possible to modify any of the profile data(for Security reasons), but all the content of the site will be related to this user obtained from the webservice, and would keep the administrators of the wordpress site, the response of the webservice is a JSON.

I have used rest api's before, but in different environments, I have never modified the wordpress core, because I think it is what I have to modify to do this authentication, if someone knows how to do this, I will thank you infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) Authentication [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/).

There has been talk of a [WP REST API Application Registry](https://apps.wp-api.org/) on Make WordPress Core's blog - [WP REST API: Introducing the Authentication Broker](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/05/16/rest-api-authentication-broker/), which would require the [OAuth 1 plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1) to work.

You can read more about the evolving rest api on the [blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/rest-api/).